# React native release bug

Tags: react-native

I faced with a problem which I can't solve.
My application works fine in debug mode, but when I build it under release and install on my device I see a bug. I've created a difficult component which I use in application and which appears using animation and this component is not shown. 
Are there any practice to solve release problems? 
How can I debug this case? 
I'm new in mobile development.

Comment: You mentioned putting the release build on your phone. Did you do an offline build of the js code, and run debug on your device as well?

Comment: yes. debug works fine on my device.

Comment: Ah okay. I ran into some issues with a release build, but it threw an error, so I just used a non minified version of the bundle in release to see what the stack trace was and went from there. Post the code for the component, and how you trigger the animation, something might stand out to others. Otherwise I would just recommend you do a clean build, double check the right bundle is getting included in release.

Comment: @alborozd Did you solve this issue?! If you did, I will be grateful if I can have your correction!